# C# async Task - Can you have more than 1 await() in a method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to make 2 async calls. The response of the first is need as the params for the second call.  Is it 'ok' to place both await's in the same method like this:

```
public static async Task<string>  GetInfo()
{
   var first = await CallOne();

   var second = await CallTwo(first);

   return second.ToString();
}
```

Thoughts?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I think it might help if you re-read the docs a bit to truly learn how async/await function

Comment: What problem would you think this will cause ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it 'ok' to place both await's in the same method

Yes.

An `await` is an "asynchronous wait"; it will pause the *method* but not block the *thread*. So, `first` is assigned *after* `CallOne` completes, and *then* `CallTwo` is invoked.

See my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more information on how `await` works.